# Symfony 4 Doctrine not working from console [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4, symfony-flex

I´m working with symfony 4 and this error ocurr when runnning doctrine console commands:

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 108:

An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

I think this is because there´s something wrong with the connection but when I run the application it has access to the database without errors, so I can not imagine what is wrong with the connection.

I was able to continue working by creating manually the database and using

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql
```

But this is really unwanted because later when the schema needs to be updated all data would be lost because i would need to re-create the schema instead of updating it.

The app works normally after executing manually the SQL (easyadmin works fine).

Here are my configurations:

.ENV:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/test
```

doctrine.yaml:

```
parameters:
     env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
       driver: 'pdo_mysql'
       server_version: '5.7'
       charset: utf8mb4
```

I tried the drop command just to test and it throwed this:

```
In DropDatabaseDoctrineCommand.php line 93:


Connection does not contain a 'path' or 'dbname' parameter and cannot be dropped.
```

So I add dbname to doctrine.yaml and didn´t worked. 
I also tried removing the cache, creating a new project, using a remote mysql, and using sqlite but the errors are the same in both cases !!

Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: I "SOLVED" it by luck when i  added the database url in the doctrine.yaml in parameters. But when the file is created the line is commented with "You should not need to change this value." I think this is kind of dirty, but it works.

Answer (score 4):

Please change `DB_HOST=localhost` to `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`

#### > doctrine/doctrine-bundle

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}
```

Answer (score 1):

So i suppose that you showed the whole content of your doctrine.yml.

If so, you might want to consider changing your doctrine.yml as follows:
add an additional line in the dbal: section

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
       driver: 'pdo_mysql'
       server_version: '5.7'
       charset: utf8mb4
       url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

Watch the last line, beginning with url:, closely.

The 'resolve:" operator looks up DATABASE_URL in your env-Variables and if it is found, it then replaces the expression with its content.

This is a doctrine.yml, that gets auto-generated by symfony.

The 'resolve' operator migth not be needed though. This could potentially work too:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
       driver: 'pdo_mysql'
       server_version: '5.7'
       charset: utf8mb4
       url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
```

This method is proposed in [the symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html), which might be interesting to read, to understand further configuration of symfony.

Comment: The resolve operator is not needed indeed. But the error keeps throwing, I´ve been working around with this error and it seems that when running commands from the console the .env variables are not loaded, i think that must be the problem.  I don`t know if maybe there are some docs where it shows how the .env works when running bin/console commands.

Answer (score 1):

My fix is here:

```
export DATABASE_URL=<value from .env>
```

And generating SQLs works :)

Answer (score 0):

## config/packages/doctrine.yaml

I solved this error adding my database url in the "config/packages/doctrine.yaml" file the "parameters" > "env(DATABASE_URL)" field:

```
parameters:
     # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
     # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
     # environment variables are not available yet.
     # You should not need to change this value.
     env(DATABASE_URL): 'mysql://your_db_url'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this change in .env file

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/test
```

to

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/test"
```

I added quotes. Maybe you are using windows? It works for me.

like in [Symfony docs: Environment Variables](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hi On my side I add the exact same behaviour, on symfony 4,
I just changed this

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@localhost:8889/
```

to this

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:8889
```

on my .env or .env.dev file (depend on the env you are working on)
hope it helps.